# How to add words to an existing vocabulary with tensorflow, contrib.learn?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was working with the tensorflow vocabulary, imported like this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
vocabulary = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(length)
```

I wrote a unit test that made sure that I could save the vocabulary, reload it, and fit a new sentence while still keeping track of the old one.

This were my results:

```
The fit sentence:  [1 2 3 4 5 6 2 7 8 4 5 9 7]
The new fit sentence:  [0 0 0 2 9 0 6 2 7 8 4 0 0]
```

It worked correctly, the word in position 0 ( processed as 2 ) in the first sentence has the same value ( 2 ) like the word in position 3 in the second sentence, because they are the same.

However, I noticed all the new words were 0.

I would have expected my new fit sentence to look like this:

```
[10 11 12 2 9 10 6 2 7 8 4 12 11]
```

How can I fix this issue? How can I make my vocabulary processor learn new words?

Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

This is a stripped down version of my unit test:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import learn

# A test sentence
test_sentence = "This is a test sentence. It is used to test. sentence, this, used"
test_sentence_len = len(test_sentence.split(" "))

# A vocabulary processor
vocabulary_processor = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(test_sentence_len)

# Turning a list of sentences ( [test_sentence] ) into a list of fit test sentences and taking the first one.
fit_test_sentence = np.array(list(vocabulary_processor.fit_transform([test_sentence])))[0]

# We see that "is" ( position 1 ) and "is" ( position 6 ) are the same. They should have the same numeric value
# in the fit array as well
print("The fit sentence: ", fit_test_sentence)
# self.assertEqual(fit_test_sentence[1], fit_test_sentence[6])

initial_fit_sentence = fit_test_sentence

# Now, let's save

vocabulary_processor.save("some/path")

# Now, we load into a different variable

new_vocabulary_processor = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor.restore("some/path")

new_test_sentence = "Very different uttering is this one. It is used to test."

# Now, we fit the new sentence with the new vocabulary, which should be the old one
# We should see "is" being transformed into the same numerical value, initial_fit_sentence[1]

new_fit_sentence = np.array(list(new_vocabulary_processor.fit_transform([new_test_sentence])))[0]

print("The new fit sentence: ", new_fit_sentence)
# self.assertEqual(initial_fit_sentence[1], new_fit_sentence[3])
```

I tried changing the values of `test_sentence_len` thinking maybe the vocabulary just couldn't learn any more new words, but even if i set it to 1000 for example, it won't learn new words.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I mean the final application

Comment: @martianwars Text classification. For that, I need to have a numerical representation of my  words. I would like to be able to learn a vocabulary, save it and when I load it, I want it to learn new words. I can save it and load it, but it marks new words with 0. This is the problem I am trying to fix.

Comment: Are you calling fit() or transform() on your new sentences? Can you show the sequence of calls you're making?

Comment: @Russell , I am using vocabulary_processor.fit_transform(). I will make an edit with a stripped down version of my unit test.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `fit_transform` method will freeze the vocabulary. This means that anything that has not been observed until that point will get the `0` ID (UNK). You can unfreeze the vocabulary with `new_vocabulary_processor.vocabulary_.freeze(False)`.

```
new_vocabulary_processor = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor.restore("some/path")
new_vocabulary_processor.vocabulary_.freeze(False)
new_test_sentence = "Very different uttering is this one. It is used to test."
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try it out!